# How to download image using WebClient.UploadString method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, image, webclient

I want to get image by sending json data to API. I use WebClient to download image.

```
string URI = "http://my_api.com";
string myParameters = "{'my': 'json_object'}";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

UploadString method's return type is string. How can I convert this result to ContentType: image/jpeg ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a jpg you need to convert the string into a byte[]... but I ask why not use WebClient.DownloadFile?

```
using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
{
    //add user agent string
    w.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
    //download to disk
    w.DownloadFile(uri, savePath);
}
```

I also added a user agent string indicating Google Chrome to the header because some servers block requests based on this, returning an HTTP forbidden error.